# Writing a Ruby class inside of a Chef Recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to "clean up" my Chef recipe to install Zabbix Agent, I know there are a million out there, but this is my test case for my understanding. I have my Chef instructions split up into a class, and separate methods for each step that would need to be completed. I put the class inside the recipe file. So, when I execute the recipe, [linked here at GitHub](https://github.com/predatorian3/zabbix_agent_corp/blob/master/recipes/recipe_zabbix_agent_unix.rb), I receive this error:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `execute' for #<Class:0x000000030e42c0>::Recipe_Zabbix_Agent_Unix
```

I'm by no means a Ruby guru, so I thought to myself, I bet this class is "separating" itself form the Chef inheritances, so I'll need to make the class inherit the Chef libraries by using the `<` thing. However, I still receive that error listed above. What am I missing, or not understanding when trying to do this? I've seen people write a library which is basically just a Ruby script, then the recipe includes the script and performs the functions in there, but I wanted to keep it contained in just the recipe for my simple understanding. Is that possible or is the only option I'm looking at doing the library route? I am running this on Chef 10.24 also.

Comment: You don't have access to the Chef DSL in heavy-weight providers.

Comment: How would I inherit those providers?

Comment: Use the class form `execute = Chef::Resource::Execute.new(command)`

Comment: Would I have to do that for each "Chef block" inside that Ruby class that I put in there?

Comment: Yes, you would have to do that.

Comment: @sethvargo do you then need to do `execute.run` or similar ??

Answer (score 2):

In general, class-based Resources go in a library file, not a recipe. See https://github.com/poise/berkshelf-api/blob/master/libraries/berkshelf_api.rb for an example of using Poise to get elements of the LWRP DSL in your class-based Resource.

Comment: So, I would write my class as a library file, then require or include it and then call the functions I want out of it?

Comment: All cookbook library files are loaded automatically by Chef at the very start of the converge.

Comment: I think both you and @sethvargo are correct because with what I'm trying to do, I'd have to do what he is saying, and assign the Chef fucntion to the object execute and such inside my class, and my class belongs in a library. Since I'm trying to call Chef functions in my class, I'm going to try sethvargo's idea first, then try putting my code in the library folder.

Comment: @Pred how did it go?

Comment: I think I failed you @vikingsteve. I ended up dropping the class idea, and just going with functions. If you check the code out I linked, I just declare some `def`'s.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that takes the recipe as a parameter so that resource-definition methods are in scope.

In `libraries/useful_thing.rb`:

```
class UsefulThing
  def initialize(blah)
    @blah = blah
  end

  def apply(recipe)
    # Chef resources use instance_eval for blocks, which hides self
    outer_self = self
    recipe.directory "/foo/#{@blah}" do
        user ...
        group outer_self.latest_group
        ...
    end
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

then in `recipes/default.rb`:

```
ut = UsefulThing.new(...)
ut.apply(self)
```